# Akka - State management in routers

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Supposing I write an akka actor as

```
class SomeActor extends Actor {
  val state =  mutable.Map[String, Long]()

  def receive = { // Do some processing on the state
  }

  override def postStop () { 
      println(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(state)))
  }
}
```

Now for load balancing if I use a Round-Robin router

```
actorSystem.actorOf(Props(classOf[SomeActor]).withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(nrOfInstances=10)))
```

How does akka manage state in such a scenario? Does akka guarantee safety in situations like these?

I would love a detailed explanation on this

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, it has nothing to do with `router`. Router only distributes the message to each individual actor and each actor of 10 has its only mutable map. Think of it as actor-confinement.

Assuming multiple messages are send to an actor. Then the answer depends on your implementation - In short: the code in your `receive`. In Akka, at a time only one actor can process `receive`. So even through an actor has 10 messages waiting to be run, each message is taken one at a time and `receive` is executed. So in a loop it happens for remaining 9 messages.

So say if your `receive` implementation is purely synchronous. Then the operation is atomic (along with memory-visibility, akka guarantees this) and hence `state` is thread-safe.

But say if it is asynchronous i.e. `with future or (actor ? msg) with pipeTo or something`, or a thread executing something which later adds to `state`. In such cases you need to synchronize `state` (IMO, the whole motto of using akka is lost). This is because multiple threads might be accessing `state`.

End answer, it depends on your implementation of `receive`

Comment: I see that there are 10 instances of the actor , So in Round robin routers, there should be no state maintained? Am I right here

Comment: @winash Sorry I do not get it. There are 10 instances of actor and each actor has its own map.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I get it now